# Javascript Append Child AFTER Element

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, appendchild, createelement

I would like to append an li element after another li inside a ul element using javascript, This is the code I have so far..

```
var parentGuest = document.getElementById("one");
var childGuest = document.createElement("li");
childGuest.id = "two";
```

I am familiar with appendChild,

```
parentGuest.appendChild(childGuest);
```

However this appends the new element inside the other, and not after. How can I append the new element after the existing one? Thanks.

```
<ul>
  <li id="one"><!-- where the new li is being put --></li>
  <!-- where I want the new li -->
</ul>
```

Comment: Show some html.. is the parent a ul or li?

Comment: I voted to reopen this QA because I want to add new updated answer as this QA still pops up as top search result on google.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You can use:

```
if (parentGuest.nextSibling) {
  parentGuest.parentNode.insertBefore(childGuest, parentGuest.nextSibling);
}
else {
  parentGuest.parentNode.appendChild(childGuest);
}
```

---

But as Pavel pointed out, the *referenceElement* can be null/undefined, and if so, [insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore) behaves just like [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild). So the following is equivalent to the above:

```
parentGuest.parentNode.insertBefore(childGuest, parentGuest.nextSibling);
```

Comment: if-else is unnecessary: the second arg of insertBefore can be null or undefined

Answer (score 19):

If you are looking for a plain JS solution, then you just use `insertBefore()` against `nextSibling`.

Something like:

```
parentGuest.parentNode.insertBefore(childGuest, parentGuest.nextSibling);
```

Note that default value of `nextSibling` is `null`, so, you don't need to do anything special for that.

**Update:** You don't even need the `if` checking presence of `parentGuest.nextSibling` like the currently accepted answer does, because if there's no next sibling, it will return `null`, and passing `null` to the 2nd argument of `insertBefore()` means: append at the end.

Reference:

- [nextSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.nextSibling)
- [insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore)

.

IF you are using jQuery (ignore otherwise, I have stated plain JS answer above), you can leverage the convenient `after()` method:

```
$("#one").after("<li id='two'>");
```

Reference:

- [jQuery after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

Comment: excuse my ignorance but how does this implement with javascript? could you show how it will work with my current code, thanks.

Comment: I think if you are not using jQuery for it, then Yoshi's answer is right. It is also mentioned here http://www.netlobo.com/javascript-insertafter.html - I just tended to assume jQuery is super default. My mistake :D

Comment: A year and half later and I get a vote up for this answer. So, I have updated it to include the shortest possible version of the plain JS solution, and a link to Mozilla docs on it. Sorry for not doing it earlier (since others did it already with very similar implementations, I didn't think I needed to).

Answer (score 17):

You need to append the new element to existing element's parent before element's next sibling. Like:

```
var parentGuest = document.getElementById("one");
var childGuest = document.createElement("li");
childGuest.id = "two";
parentGuest.parentNode.insertBefore(childGuest, parentGuest.nextSibling);
```

Or if you want just append it, then:

```
var parentGuest = document.getElementById("one"); 
var childGuest = document.createElement("li"); 
childGuest.id = "two"; 
parentGuest.parentNode.appendChild(childGuest);
```

Answer (score 5):

## after is now a JavaScript method

[MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/after)

Quoting MDN

> The `ChildNode.after()` method inserts a set of Node or `DOMString` objects in the children list of this `ChildNode`'s parent, just after this `ChildNode`. DOMString objects are inserted as equivalent Text nodes.

The browser support is Chrome(54+), Firefox(49+) and Opera(39+). It doesn't support IE and Edge.

### Snippet

```js
var elm=document.getElementById('div1');
var elm1 = document.createElement('p');
var elm2 = elm1.cloneNode();
elm.append(elm1,elm2);

//added 2 paragraphs
elm1.after("This is sample text");
//added a text content
elm1.after(document.createElement("span"));
//added an element
console.log(elm.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
```

In the snippet, I used another term [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append) too

Answer (score 2):

Use the parent element `children` array.
In the example below we are adding a new element after the first child element (hence we will insert the new element before the element in index 1):

```
parentElement.insertBefore(newElement, parentElement.children[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

This suffices :

```
 parentGuest.parentNode.insertBefore(childGuest, parentGuest.nextSibling || null);
```

since if the `refnode` (second parameter) is null, a regular appendChild is performed. see here : http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Node/insertBefore

Actually I doubt that the `|| null` is required, try it and see.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do

```
function insertAfter(node1, node2) {
    node1.outerHTML += node2.outerHTML;
}
```

or

```
function insertAfter2(node1, node2) {
    var wrap = document.createElement("div");
    wrap.appendChild(node2.cloneNode(true));
    var node2Html = wrap.innerHTML;
    node1.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', node2Html);
}
```