# How to append a node to preferred place in js

Tags: javascript, dom, append

I have an ordered list in HTML.

```
<ol class="btns">
  <li>First item</li>
  <li>Second item</li>
  <!--Third one goes here-->
  <li>Four item</li>
</ol>
```

I want to add a new list item with js into third order. How can I do that?

Here's demo: http://jsbin.com/akahow/2/edit

*More info*: `appendChild` adds new item to end of list, I tried `insertBefore` but failed, only I could done with `insertBefore` adding it to first place. But I want to put it third place.

Comment: Try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258185/javascript-append-child-after-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/k6xVc/

```
var paragraph = document.createElement("li");
var textNode = document.createTextNode("Third item");
paragraph.appendChild(textNode);
var list=document.getElementById("jack");
list.insertBefore(paragraph,list.childNodes[4]);​
```

HTML:

```
<ol class="btns" id="jack">
  <li>First item</li>
  <li>Second item</li>
  <!--Third one goes here-->
  <li>Four item</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: An id shouldn't start with a number.

Comment: @Jack ok but in HTML5 it's ok... and that was only example

Comment: It's still better avoided, even for examples.

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is that you've used `getElementsByClassName`, which returns an array of nodes, even if the array only contains one node. If you are absolutely sure that there is one and only one element with that class, you should change the line to:

```
var findmenu = document.getElementsByClassName("btns")[0];
```

Then you need to use `insertBefore` to insert the item into the stack. However, `insertBefore` requires a reference to the actual object in front of which you want to insert your node, not the index. In your case, you'd add the line:

```
findmenu.insertBefore(paragraph,findmenu.childNodes[4]);
```

You may notice that we had to use the fifth index (`[4]`) to insert the node into the correct place. This is because the `childNodes` array includes all types of nodes, including Text, Elements and Comments.

Comment: Thanks for comprehensive explanation. Is it possible to eliminate other types of nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Get 2nd `<li>`  as element and append to that by using `appendChild`

Check this [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/akahow/15/edit)